# Changing PHP code which uses PHPs $_REQUEST super global

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, request, global

New to php and have read up on $_REQUEST being strongly discouraged, due to the fact that it makes it nearly impossible to determine the source of the data, and also being a security risk as well.

Not sure what the best way would be to change the following code, to update the code, so that the $_REQUEST is replaced with something better?

```
public static function sales_data_postback() {
    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['sales_data'] ) )
        return;

    $data          = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['data'] ) );
    $cart_contents = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['cart_contents'] ) );

    //Unset purchase log ID, since we're inserting a new one.
    $data = (array) $data;

    unset( $data['id'] );

    $purchase_log = wpsc_get_order( $data );
    $purchase_log->save();
    $purchase_log_id = $purchase_log->get( 'id' );

    global $wpdb;

    //We need to update the proper product ID, name and purchase ID
    foreach ( $cart_contents as $cart_item ) {

        $product = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'wpsc-product', 'pagename' => $cart_item->slug ) );
        $product = $product->get_posts();
        $product = $product[0];

        $cart_item = ( array ) $cart_item;

        unset( $cart_item['id'] );
        unset( $cart_item['slug'] );

        $cart_item['prodid']     = $product->ID;
        $cart_item['name']       = $product->post_title;
        $cart_item['purchaseid'] = $purchase_log_id;

        $wpdb->insert( WPSC_TABLE_CART_CONTENTS, $cart_item );
    }

    die;
}
```

Comment: If the variable is expected only through a POST request then use $_POST instead. Or use $_GET if the opposite is true.

Comment: Thanks ADyson. In terms of security, if I use either of the $_POST or $_GET, is there anything else that I should look at with the above code?

Comment: You could check if the user is logged in first and if they have different permission levels, depending on who you want his to execute for, and you can also check for a nonce that you've generated.